# Spring Boot - Does not delete by Delete mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have orders table and i want delete one by pressing the button.
I have such methods in my controller :

```
@GetMapping("/orderListAdmin/decline")
private String declineOrder(){
    return "redirect:/orderListAdmin";
}

@DeleteMapping("/orderListAdmin/decline")
private void deleteOrder(@RequestParam("Id") long id){
    orderService.deleteOrderById(id);
}
```

the get mapping  method return page where orders are displayed:

```
@GetMapping("/orderListAdmin")
private String getOrderListAdmin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("masterorders",orderService.findAll());

    return "orderListAdmin";
}
```

in thymeleaf i have such code( where masterorder is:th:each="masterorder : ${masterorders}   )

```
 <form action="/orderListAdmin/decline" th:method="delete" >
      <input type="hidden" th:value="${masterorder.id}" th:attr="name='Id'"/>
      <button type="submit" class="buttondecline"  th:text="Decline">
      </button>
 </form>
```

The problem is url becomes like my method name: /orderListAdmin/decline

And page is empty, without headers and orders that had been displayed before i pressed the button.
Probably, it does not delete order.
I delete it like that:

In OrderRepository class added method

```
void deleteOrderById(long id);
```

And in order Service class i have

```
public void deleteOrderById(long id) {
    orderRepository.deleteOrderById(id);
}
```

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try debugging?. is your id coming to decline method. If it is a pathvariable you need to use @PathVariable annotation

Comment: @venkat, Yes , tried debugging. Id comes to decline method. "If it is a pathvariable you need to use PathVariable annotation" - May i do it with requestParam somehow?

Comment: PathVariable is something to use when the URL is. -- orderListAdmin/decline/{orderId} 

RequestParam should be used to when the URL is -- 
orderListAdmin/decline?orderId={orderId}

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the page is being empty, deleteOrder method is void therefore there is no redirection or any response, I suspect submitting the form causes the page to change to response from the server. You may want to return a ResponseEntity that represents the result of the request at least to tackle this.

You mentioned while debug you can see the "Id", assuming orderService is autowired correctly the issue might be with the deleteOrderById method. Is there a @Transactional(readOnly = true) setting that prevents altering the database?

Also why use "private" in your controller methods? As far as I know it is not useful in any way.